# What is the proper way to store items using Shelve?

Tags: python

I want to store records using a simple flat file instead of SQLite. The data that is maintained follows this format:

```
<Name> <Assignment> <Grade>
```

I made a simple class called StudentRecord,

```
class StudentRecord:
    def __init__(self, name, assignment, grade):
        self.name = name
        self.assignment = assignment
        self.grade = grade
```

to use to put into the database. I'd like the file to represent something **logically** that resembles  this:

```
Bob Test1 99                (StudentRecord Object)
John Worksheet 39           (StudentRecord Object)
Chris Quiz 77               (StudentRecord Object)
```

What would the key be for each object that I store? I'd like to read all of these individual objects back in, and also append to this database.

Comment: 1) `shelve` pickles the data, hence you *cannot* save the data in a text format using it 2) It uses a database to store the data, so you *definitely* cannot use `shelve` to store the data in plain format. What you want is a so-called comma-separated values file, aka [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: That's not what I was asking for. I edited the question to make it more clear. The database is storing objects, each object is a StudentRecord. How do I assign key values to these, as to not overlap them for each object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something this structured a sqlite database might actually be best.  If you don't want to deal with SQL, you could use [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/), or for a pure in-memory ORM which can serialise to and from sqlite, there's [norman](https://norman.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).  However, if you're really set on shelve, then it just depends how you want to access the data.  As its a key-value store, you need to represent each object you're storing as a dict, which means you need to decide how you want to look up records.  For example, you could structure it by name:

```
{
    'Bob': {'assignment': 'Test1', grade: 99},
    'John': {'assignment': 'Worksheet', grade: 39}
}
```

Of course, that only works if you can guarantee that each name is unique.  Alternatively you could create a unique id (e.g. a UUID or just an auto-assigned integer), but once you start down that path you'll very quickly find yourself creating your "sqliteish" implementation.  This also assumes that you want to access each each object as a whole, but if your table is really that simple I'm not sure why you wouldn't.